# In jspdf-Autotable how to align content of footer columns the same as in data columns?

Tags: typescript, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to create PDF table using jspdf-Autotable. The table has some columns and rows and has 4 footer rows. 1 row for SUMS, 2nd row for AVERAGES, 3rd for MIN, 4th for MAX values of the data above in given numeric columns.

I want the numeric values aligned right and naturally the results of the sums/calculations in the footers also right.

I know how to align the data in the data columns - using the code here, but
cannot figure out how to align the data in the columns of the 4 footer rows.

```
  body: data,
  columnStyles: {[key: string]: Partial<Styles>} = {
                          0: {halign: 'right' },
                          3: {halign: 'justify'},
                          5: {halign: 'center' },
                          8: {halign: 'left' },
                        },
  foot: footData,
                       // THIS IS WHAT I'D BE HOPING FOR TO ALIGN MY FOOTERS
                       // THE SAME AS MY DATA COLUMNS, BUT THERE IS NO SUCH PROPERTY
  footerColumnStyles: {[key: string]: Partial<Styles>} = {
                          0: {halign: 'right' },
                          3: {halign: 'justify'},
                          5: {halign: 'center' },
                          8: {halign: 'left' },
                        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, Here is a rough snippet of it for those looking for the same.

```
body: data,
foot: footData,
. . .,
didParseCell: (data) => {
  data.table.foot.forEach((footRow) => {
    myColumnFormats.forEach((colFormat,i) => {
      if (colFormat.isNumeric) {
         footRow.cells[i].styles.halign = 'right';
      }
    })
  }) ;
},
...
```